# On how to find the maximum point of a formula.

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I need help finding out how to find the maximum of a formula I devised, given the starting conditions.

$$y = \sqrt{{\frac{{mx^2v^2 - 2xF}}{{m}}}}$$

or, adding in the values of F,

$$y = \sqrt\frac{{mx^2v^2 - xpcA(w - xv)^2}}{{m}}$$

No variable can equal 0, except for y. x should be undefined at 0.

When placing this is Desmos, it graphs a function with a maximum, I have found that,  it hits 0 at 2F/mv<sup>2</sup>. But I have yet to be able to find out when it hits the maximum and begins to decrease.

To further make myself clear, x is changing and I need to find a formula which says at what x, given the other variables, would y reach the maximum. Formula 2 is more relevant as it separates F into the different variables.

How exactly would I go about finding this maximum? I know how to do it with simpler functions, but how can I find a formula for the maximum of a more complicated one like this. I need to be able to find both the x and y of the maximum.

I am sorry if this is a lot of work, I am just not sure how to do things like this myself. At least I want to be taught how to be able to find the Maxima of complex functions, so that I can solve the problem myself.

Edit: Cleared up some confusion with variables, and specified my question better.

The Derivative I got

$$y = \frac{(cAxpw^2 - 2cAx^2 vpw + cAx^3v^2p)}{m^2}$$

setting to 0 gets $x = \frac{w}{v}$ and $x = 0$, which only seem to describe the zeros of the numerator of the derivative, and when placed into the original formula, does not get the correct value of x.

Edit: I am just giving up on this, no matter what I try I can't find the right answer, and it is proving stressful and taxing on my mental health. Need to stop focusing on it for my own sake.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: Could there be an error in your formulas? I'm assuming F is force, m is mass, a is acceleration and v is velocity . When you divide m into F and cancel the first m, you are subtracting the square of an acceleration from the product of and acceleration and velocity squared.  So the units don't match up. Also what are you varying? if F is zero and av are arbitrary, then you can make y arbitrarily large.

Comment: If a is your dependent variable, using calculus gives you the max happens at $2F=mv^2$

Comment: You have a formula involving five variables, $y,m,a,v,F$ and you want the $x$-value of the maximum, when there isn't any $x$ in your formula. What are you talking about? Not to mention variables $p,c$, and $v_2$. Please edit your question so it makes sense.

Comment: @Turloc, from the way the formula is written, I'd think $y$ was the dependent variable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I said that a = x.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed F is drag force. Which, as I showed is 0.5pu<sup>2</sup>cA, and spread it out throughout the formula in the second formula. All of the values except a are constant from the start. With a changing, so it is basically given values of m, v, p, A, c, and u; what would it equal at a = x. Furthermore, a is not acceleration, but I understand your mistunderstanding, a is just a value that shows the factor in which mass is decreased, in the form of 1/a * m.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, I see now how you made that mistake.

Comment: The edit has improved the question. But I see a reference to $X$ which is not used anywhere. Was that supposed to be $x$? Also, when you write, "All of the values except $a$ [which we now call $x$] are constant from the start," that doesn't apply to $F$, does it? $F$ seems to be a function of $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134439/discussion-between-zoey-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. Meanwhile, I posted an answer – any thoughts on it?

Comment: @Zoey is this problem related to phys?

Comment: Somewhat, it takes advantage of physics of drag and conservation of momentum, but it assumes the case of one capable of instantly changing their mass, while remaining the same size. Which isn't a physical possibility.

Comment: @Zoey can you write what the things are representing in a row in the question then I hope it will be better for us to make an attempt

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the formula as $$y=\sqrt{Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx}$$ where my $A,B,C$ are functions of your constants $m,v,p,c,A,w$. The cubic is zero at $x=0$ and also at the zeros of the quadratic $Ax^2+Bx+C$. Assuming the formula makes physical sense, and the cubic is positive for sufficiently small, positive values of $x$, the quadratic has two real zeros, one positive and one negative, and $y$ is positive between $x=0$ and the positive root of the quadratic, rising to a unique maximum in that interval (note that my $A$ is negative).

Now $y$ is maximized where $y^2$ is, so it's just a matter of differentiating the cubic, setting the resulting quadratic to zero, and solving for the positive value of $x$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134513/discussion-on-answer-by-gerry-myerson-on-how-to-find-the-maximum-point-of-a-form).

Answer (score 0):

Function is maximum when its second derivative is less than zero. You need to check that condition first. After checking, you need to equate first derivative to zero and find x. Substitute this value of x in y and you will find answer.

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't come out neatly, it comes out as a very long and complex formula which isn't explicitly negative. Though at the same time, when I calculate it out, it does actually have a maximum. I tried placing in the solution to the first derivative as well, and got y = w as the answer. Which is wrong. It is the fact that this didn't work that led me to try to ask here.

Comment: But thank you for the attempt to help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I hope if some one view this in physical aspect then the first equation will become this( all the thing varying with respect to time) so why dt is used and after solving this we can get an equation in x and y w.r.t.t like f(x(t),y(t)) and it is hoped then we can find max or min as we do in multivariate calculus

y${\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt}}$=x(${\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}}$)${^3}$+${x^2}$${\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}}$ - x${\displaystyle\frac{d^3 x}{dt^3}}$ - ${\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}}$

Comment: If everything is a function of $t$ then this is certainly something OP is hiding from us, but in any event I don't see where your formula comes from and in particular why the 2nd & 3rd derivatives of $x$ have anything to do with it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what I have answered is in view of physics there F = force = m$(\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2})$ so if we divide the parts inside the root m will cancelled and on the other half m is there so dividing by m will eliminate that part m also and after that to find the max again derivative it w.r.t. time as the one who asked questions replied in my comment that everything is varying so it is expected to vary with time so the 3rd and 2nd derivative come . Hope it is ok now.

Comment: The F in question represents Drag Force, I just didn't put the subscript F to specify because I gave the form with the Drag formula put in instead of F.

Comment: @Zoey then it seems to be a problem of fluid dynamics but still hope can be solved by this after all force can be represented by m ×a and hope in that thing at the 2nd expression you will get a similar differential equation and by solving those 2 differential equation the rusult will become